# How to draw lines between a text and a bar in Barplot using R

Tags: r

I am plotting the barplot in R. I am new to R.

I need to achieve the output from the code like the following pdf file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrUFcwbTY5eU9mbDA/view?usp=sharing

From the pdf file if you see , there are lines connecting the bar and the text.I am not able to achieve the same in R. Can anyone help me with this.

Following is my code .

```
# Reading from the csv file 
hotdogs <-read.csv("hot-dogcontest-winners.csv",sep=",", header=TRUE)

# Colouring the bar based on conditions. 
fill_colors <- c()
for ( i in 1:length(hotdogs$New.record) ){
    if (hotdogs$New.record[i] == "1") {
        fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#31D331")
    } 
   else 
   {
        fill_colors <- c(fill_colors, "#D5D8D4")
   }
   }

# Output to a pdf file.
pdf("my_plot.pdf", width=25, height=10)

# Plotting the bar graph.
barplot(hotdogs$Dogs.eaten, names.arg=hotdogs$Year, col=fill_colors,space=0.5,xlab="Year",border=NA,ylab="Hot dogs and buns (HDB) eaten"
,main="Nathan's Hot Dog Eating Contest Results from 1980-2017")


axis(1, at = seq(1980,2016, by = 2),col="black",tcl=0)

# Making the yaxis not visible.
axis(2, col = "white", tcl = 0)

# Creating texts and placing it in certain co-ordinates.
text(10,65,"Nathan's hot dog eating contest every July 4th has been going on since the early 1900s,but it wasn't
until 2001,when things got serious.Takeru Kobayashi from Japan raised the bar, more than doubling 
the previous world record.Highlighted bars indicate new records.")

text(30,65,"Matthew Stonnie won in 2015 , after Joey Chestnut won 8 consecutive times")


text(10,25,"Frank Dellarosa sets a new 
world record with 21 and half HDBs")

text(20,55,"In 2001,Takeru Kobayashi, gets his first
win in the competition.He went on to win five
more years in a row.")
```

So far able to achieve this.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrcThwekxxc09MeFk/view?usp=sharing

The csv data is present in this location

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrdXFranV6YlNKYUE/view

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: We cannot run your code because we do not have the data file.  Can you post the data as well?  It may be easiest to run `dput(hotdogs)` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: Make a more simple example. (Since this is base graphics, the `lines` function could be used.)

Comment: Hi,The csv file is in the following location

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3XlF206d5UrdXFranV6YlNKYUE/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used segment(x0, y0, x1, y1) method to plot lines everywhere.